# Strange empty space in CSS table

Tags: html, css

http://corexii.com/web/shinji-eme/empty-space-problem.png

I cannot for the life of me figure out why that empty space is there. It's inside of `section .Blog`. Removing the `section .SidepanelPanel` (the ad) makes it go away. Some different content for `.SidepanelPanel` doesn't cause this to happen leading me to believe it has something to do with the link + image contents of the `.SidepanelPanel`... but why? And how to fix?

Comment: interesting. i can't tell you why, but when i threw this into jsfiddle, it works http://fiddle.jshell.net/fPZrr/show/

Comment: @albert The ad image got replaced by its alt-text on jsfiddle, so clearly the problem lies with the image somehow affecting the content flow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you apply `vertical-align: top;` to `.Blog`, the large gap goes away.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I guess the reason is the default value of vertical-align is `vertical-align: baseline`. While you have two cells with different height, that will align `.blog` and `.SidePanel` with the bottom.